# Multiscale search for HOG+SVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, multiscaleimage

first of all this is my first question here, so I hope I can explain it in a clear way.

My goal is to detect different classes of traffic signs in images. For that purpose I have trained binary SVMs following these steps:

- First I got a database of cropped traffic signs like the one in the link. I considered different classes (prohibition, danger, etc), and negative images. All of them were scaled to 40x40 pixels.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf8ub.jpg

- I trained linear-SVM models for each class (1-vs-all), using HOG as feature. Each image is described with a 1728-dimensional feature. (I append the three feature vectors for all three image planes). I did crossvalidation to set parameter C, and tested on previously unseen 40x40 images, and I got very accurate results (F1 score over 0.9 for all classes). I used libsvm for training and testing.

Now I'd want to detect signs in full road images, sliding a window in different image scales. The problem I'm facing is that I couldn't find any function that can do it for me (as DetectMultiScale in OpenCV), and my solution is very slow and rudimentary (I'm just doing a triple for loop, and for each scale I crop consecutive and overlapping 40x40 images, obtain HOG features and apply *svmpredict* for each one).

Can someone give me a clue to find a faster way to do it? I thought too about getting the HOG feature vector of the whole input image, and then reorder that vector to a matrix where each row will have the features corresponding to each 40x40 window, but I couldn't find a straightforward way of doing it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using SURF feature detection, however I don't know if this would also be too slow your needs.

See : http://morf.lv/modules.php?name=tutorials&lasit=2 for more information on how to implement and weather it is a viable solution for you.